# Computing Factor Group step-by-step manually

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am reading *Fraleigh*'s Abstract Algebra $\S$15 on factor group, Example #15.11:

> Compute factor group $(\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_6) / \langle (2, 3)\rangle.$

The text gives a solution that is only a shortcut and I think it's applicable only to this problem. I would like to do it in manually, dumbly, in step-by-step fashion such that I can internalize the concept better; admittedly factor group is a hard concept for beginners.

I did the following tediously:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_6 = \{ &(0, 0), (0,1), (0,2), (0, 3),(0, 4), (0,5),\\
&(1, 0), (1,1), (1,2), (1, 3),(1, 4), (1,5),\\
&(2, 0), (2,1), (2,2), (2, 3),(2, 4), (2,5),\\
&(3, 0), (3,1), (3,2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3,5)\}
\end{align}$$

Questions: 
(1) Is it possible to manually solve the problem like this? 
(2) If it is, how do I mode out each of them with $\langle (2, 3) \rangle$? Just give me a few examples.

The text says the factor group is isomorphic to either $\mathbb Z_{12}$ or $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_3$. Thank you for yoru time and effort.

---

**Post Script**: I must admit that there is a *possible* duplicate [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684998/compute-factor-group-dfrac-mathbbz-4-times-mathbbz-6-langle2-3-rang?rq=1) which I found out belated only after I posted mine. But keep in mind that my question is about how to solve it manually to enforce my understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll show you how to compute it manually.

The elements of the factor (or quotient) group are the cosets of the subgroup $H=\langle (2,3)\rangle$, which is normal in $\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_6$ because $\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_6$ is abelian.

To find all the cosets, we take each element $(h,k) \in \Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_6$ and  compute $$(h,k)+H =\{ (h,k)+(0,0), (h,k)+(2,3)\} = \{(h,k), (h+2,k+3)\}.$$ Doing this, we get the following:

$$
H = \{(0,0), (2,3)\}\\
(0,1)+H=\{(0,1),(2,4)\}\\
(0,2)+H=\{(0,2), (2,5)\}\\
(0,3)+H=\{(0,3), (2,0)\}\\
(0,4)+H = \{(0,4), (2,1)\}\\
(0,5)+H = \{(0,5), (2,2)\}\\
(1,0)+H = \{(1,0), (3,3)\}\\
(1,1)+H = \{(1,1), (3,4)\}\\
(1,2)+H = \{(1,2), (3,5)\}\\
(1,3)+H = \{(1,3), (3,0)\}\\
(1,4)+H = \{(1,4), (3,1)\}\\
(1,5)+H = \{(1,5), (3,2)\}
$$

We know that we're done once we have a partition of $\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_6$. To check this, just check that every element of $\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_6$ is in one of the cosets.

(This idea of the cosets being the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation $a \sim b \iff a-b \in H$ is used in the proof of Langrange's theorem, and it also explains why two cosets are either disjoint or equal; it's a property of equivalence classes.)

We could also argue that we've found all the cosets by using Lagrange's theorem, which tells us that the  factor (or quotient) group should have 12 elements: $$[\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_6 : \langle (2,3)\rangle] = \frac{|\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_6|}{|\langle (2,3)\rangle|} = \frac {24}{2}=12.$$

---

Now, to prove this group is isomorphic to $Z_{12}$, you could, as A.P. did, use the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, or you could show directly that the group is cyclic (because all cyclic groups of a given order are isomorphic):

To show $G= \Bbb Z_4 \times Z_6 / \langle(2,3)\rangle$ is cyclic, we will show that the element $(1,1)+H$ has order 12:

We know its order must divide $|G|=12$, so it can be $1,2,3,4, 6,$ or $12$.

Its order is not 1 because $(1,1)+H \neq H$, the identity of $G$.

Its order is not $2,3,$ or $6$, because $6((1,1)+H)= (6,6)+H=(2,0)+H \neq H$

Its order is not $4$ because $4((1,1)+H)=(4,4)+H = (0,4)+H \neq H$.

Thus, its order is 12, meaning  $\Bbb Z_4 \times Z_6 / \langle(2,3)\rangle = \langle (1,1)+H \rangle$ is cyclic, so $$\Bbb Z_4 \times Z_6 / \langle(2,3)\rangle \cong \Bbb Z_{12} \cong \Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_4$$.

Comment: +1 And now for the boring part: writing out the addition table for those classes and figuring out which group we have. :)

Comment: Eek, I'll let someone else do that. I'll edit something else in for that part.

Comment: Note that $(1,1) + H \neq H$, and $2((1,1) + H) = (2,2) + H \neq H$, and that $3((1,1) + H) = (3,3) + H \neq H$, and also $4((1,1) + H) = (0,4) + H \neq H$, and finally: $6((1,1) + H) = (2,0) + H \neq H$, which shows that $(1,1) + H$ does not have additive order $1,2,3,4$ or $6$, and therefore must have order $12$ (the only divisor of $12$ left), and thus generates $(\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_6)/\langle(2,3)\rangle$, which is therefore cyclic, of order $12$.

Comment: @DavidWheeler yes, but the fact that $6(1,1)+H\neq H$ implies that the order of $(1,1)+H$ does not divide 6, so it cannot be $2$ or $3$.

Comment: Indeed, it's more efficient to rule out maximal divisors ($6$ and $4$) of $12$ first.

Comment: @coldnumber : Thank you. You have earned my upvote and green check mark.

Answer (score 2):

We can definitely compute quotients of finite groups by inspecting each element, but one almost never does, because it is a tedious and error prone process.

In this case, note that
$$
(2,3) + (2,3) = (4,6) \equiv (0,0)
$$
so $(2,3)$ has order $2$, i.e. that $\langle (2,3) \rangle = \{(0,0),(2,3)\}$. This means that the quotient group has cardinality $24/2 = 12$, so by the [fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group#Classification) the quotient is either $\Bbb{Z}_{12} \simeq \Bbb{Z}_4 \times \Bbb{Z}_3$ (the isomorphism is due to the Chinese Remainder Theorem) or $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_3$.

We can easily distinguish between those two cases, because the latter doesn't have any elements of order $4$. Indeed, observe that, say
$$
(1,0),(2,0),(3,0) \notin \langle (2,3) \rangle
$$
which means that the class of $(1,0)$ has order $4$ in the quotient. Thus $(\Bbb{Z}_4 \times \Bbb{Z}_6) / \langle (2,3) \rangle \simeq \Bbb{Z}_{12}$.

Comment: Thanks. I pretty much understand your explanation, up to the 3rd. paragraph when you said "We can easily distinguish between..." Here are my two questions: (1) Why do you choose element of order 4 to distinguish between $\mathbb Z_{12}$ and $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$ in the first place? What is the significance of order 4 in this quest here? (I will ask the second question on the next comment space.) Thanks again.

Comment: And here is my second question: (2) I understand when you said that $(1,0),(2,0),(3,0) \notin \langle (2,3) \rangle.$ But I did not see the relationship to your next assertion that "... which means that the class of $(0, 1)$ has order 4 in the quotient. Thanks again and again for your time and effort.

Comment: @A.Magnus for (1): $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ has no element of order 4 because every nonidentity element has order 2 (so  $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_3$ has only elements of orders 1, 2, 3, and 6), whereas in $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_3$, the element (1,0,0) has order 4. The existence of an element of order four in $\Bbb Z_4$ is the easiest way to show that it is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: I refer you to coldnumber's explanation for (1). As for (2), recall that the order of an element $x$ of a group $G$ (in additive notation) is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $nx = 0$ (if it exists). Now, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then we know that $n(x + H) = nx + H$ and that the class of $x$ in $G/H$ is $0$ if and only if $x \in H$. Since $(1,0)$ has order $4$ in $\Bbb{Z}_4 \times \Bbb{Z}_6$, it is enough to check that $n(1,0) \notin \langle (2,3) \rangle$ for $1 \leq n \leq 3$.

Comment: Actually, checking $n \in \{1,2\}$ is enough because one can show that, for every $x \in G$, the order of the class of $x$ in $G/H$ divides the order of $x$ in $G$.

Comment: @coldnumber : Many thanks to Coldnumber and A.P. Give me some times to digest yours. In the meantime, is there anyone out there willing to compute the factor group manually as I originally asked. I know it is tedious, as A.P. has pointed out, but I would like to see the making of a factor group in action. Thank you again.